# Accessing and Uploading Audio Files in React Native for both iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is there a recommended way to access and upload audio files located on the filesystem and cloud services such as dropbox, drive, iCloud, etc on both Android and iOS?

I see this library https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs but it's limited to just documents on Android it looks like and I don't know if it allows you to access dropbox, drive, iCloud, etc.

I also see this library which seems based on the one above and lets you access cloud storage services but looks like it's limited to documents as well https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker

Any suggestions?

Thanks!